# The best way to make MacVim's vim (console, not mvim) the default instead of Mac OS X's vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I installed MacVim using homebrew. (`brew install macvim`). If I call `mvim` from `cmd`, it opens the GUI MacVim.

I would like to make `vim` call the MacVim's Vim (`/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`) instead of the system's (`/usr/bin/vim`) vim. Which is the best way to do it? I know I can do an `alias vim="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"` but I don't know if it's the best approach...

**EDIT**: Guys, thank for all your answers, but indeed, since I'm already using `homebrew`, using the `--override-system-vim` is the elegant way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: What's the difference between MacVim console vim and just regular vim in Terminal?

Comment: @hobbes3, the vim that ships with osx does not have ruby or python support compiled in. MacVim's vim does. Which is necessary if you want to use plugins like Command-T

Comment: The vim that ships with OS X also doesn't support the freakin' clipboard.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

This will create vim, vimdiff, etc. symlinks to mvim in /usr/local/bin/vim, and as long as /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin in your PATH, you'll get the results you're looking for.

Earlier versions of brew used the switch `--override-system-vim` which was deprecated.

Comment: Since I said I'm already using homebrew, I think this is indeed the best option: I didn't know this option was possible. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, this is a hidden gem in the vim formula, rather than homebrew itself. :)

Comment: I wonder, what if I do an brew remove macvim, will that remove macvim and leave the original vim? Or that will also be gone?

Comment: @BenMezger: Homebrew doesn't touch your original binaries, it installs packages at your /usr/local. So when you remove macvim, you're with original Mac OSX's vim.

Comment: This apparently needs the full Xcode installed via the app store (and not just the command line tools).

Comment: Nope. Does not work.

Comment: High Sierra macOS 10.13 required preliminary step to build properly: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` following this the brew install worked with-override-system-vim.

Comment: This no longer works, because homebrew has removed all formula options going forward. https://discourse.brew.sh/t/macvim-override-system-vim-even-when-using-bottled-version/1751

Answer (score 19):

The Vi command line switch works.

`alias vim='mvim -v'`

Comment: Best answer right here.

Answer (score 17):

You can create an alias in your `~/.bash_profile`, just add this line to that file:

```
alias vim="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"
```

Comment: Actually, it would be `alias vim="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"`, since I want to link to the MacVim's console vim and not the gui version.

Comment: Ahh, alright. Fixed!

Comment: Since vim is an interactive application, doing an alias that overrides the System's Vim isn't going to be that harmful, I guess...

Comment: For me this was in /Applications. Nice alias!

Answer (score 4):

`brew install macvim --override-system-vim` is deprecated. You should use `brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim` instead.

Comment: No longer works.

Answer (score 3):

To change the system's default editor add the following to your .bash_profile

```
export EDITOR=/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/<version>/bin/mvim
```

Changing this should allow you to use MacVim for the default editor (even for the app that autolaunch the editor)

**EDIT**
For normal usage at the terminal, you would still have to use 'mvim' to edit a file.  If you still want to type 'vi' on the terminal, I would suggest adding the alias to the .bash_profile as well.

**EDIT 2**
After seeing the OP's edit, you could prepend the the path of MacVim's vim to the system path.  Note I do not think this is the **best** way because it could effect other system calls as well while making calls at the terminal.  So if you really just want it to change when you type 'vim' at the command line then the use of an alias I believe to be the cleanest and *safest* thing to do.

```
PATH="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Test your settings by using `which vim` at the terminal.

Comment: I don't want to make mvim the default. I want to call MacVim's vim (`/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`) when I write down vim on terminal instead of system's vim (`/usr/bin/vim`).

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS: Sorry about that, mis-understood your intent (makes a bit more since now viewing your edit).

Comment: Hum, but you gave me an idea: if I symlink `vim` to `/usr/local/bin` and using the `$PATH` approach, it may work.

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS: Be careful symlinking to a directory that already has vim in it... It might become difficult to know which vim you're going to get.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking about `/usr/local/bin` and not `/usr/bin`. homebrew uses `/usr/local/bin` for some formulas so I don't think it's going to be a problem.

Comment: :)  My mind jumped to the worst case (local removed).  You should be fine with user local.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: just install homebrew (worth the hassle!) and `brew install vim`

My old answer is below:

---

I don't want to install xcode just for this, also I don't want to use aliases or brew method (which also requires xcode) so I do this:

1. I first download MacVim from the [releases page](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases),
2. Then I install MacVim by dragging it to my Applications folder,
3. For terminal usage, there's also a terminal app in the zip, called `mvim`, I install it by running this command:

   sudo mv mvim /usr/local/bin/vim
4. And then, I rehash the environment by `hash -r` (or close and re-open the terminal).
5. Finally, when I run `vim` from my terminal I see the updated one "in the console".

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I use homebrew for lots of stuff. It's worth the hassle. Having XCode installed but being able to install all I need just by calling `brew install` is great.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents, I run this whenever upgraded my python via `homebrew`.

```
brew reinstall vim --HEAD --with-cscope --with-lua --override-system-vim
brew reinstall macvim --HEAD --with-cscope --with-lua --override-system-vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the override for vim using:

```
brew install macvim -- --with-override-system-vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script to link macvim as system vim commands (vim, view, vimdiff, gvim, gview, gvimdiff) without using homebrew:

**Note it installs to your home directory `~/.local/bin`. So you'll need to ensure that's on your PATH**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

MVIM_DIR="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin"
DEST_DIR="$HOME/.local/bin"
mkdir -p "$DEST_DIR"

(
cd "$MVIM_DIR" || {
    echo "Cannot change to dir $MVIM_DIR"
    exit 2
}

for fn in vim vimdiff view gvim gvimdiff gview; do
    target="$(pwd)/$fn"
    echo "Linking $target into $DEST_DIR..."
    ln -sf "$target" "$DEST_DIR"
done
)
```