# macOS Console Vim Python3 Install

Tags: mac, unix, vim, python3, macvim

I know this question has been asked in many various forms, but I have not yet been able to get any of the answers to work. If anybody can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

**The Issue(s)**

I've got MacVim installed on an iMac running High Sierra - I want to purely run console `vim` as it integrates with `ranger` much better (and therefore makes file organisation a breeze). Currently, `vim --version` returns

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 18 2020 06:05:14)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283, 1365
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

indicating that Apple's `vim` is in fact recognised. `brew` will install `vim` but it won't symlink it and returns the following error after `brew link vim`:

```
Error: Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.
```

My whole escapade that led me to here is because I need `vim` to run with `+python3` but, as mentioned before in other answers, Apple's `vim` uses `python2`. Recently `brew` would install and symlink `vim`, but for whatever reason it has ceased to do so. My question is twofold:

1) How can I get `brew` to successfully symlink its version of `vim`?

2) What do I need to do to get `brew`'s `vim` to be my primary `vim` (as it is installed with `python3`)?

**Additional Info**

Here are a couple threads I've found that have not worked as of yet:

[The best way to make MacVim's vim (console, not mvim) the default instead of Mac OS X's vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/334252/the-best-way-to-make-macvims-vim-console-not-mvim-the-default-instead-of-mac) uses a deprecated method which no longer works with `brew`

[How do I install vim on OSX with Python 3 support?](https://superuser.com/questions/1115159/how-do-i-install-vim-on-osx-with-python-3-support) this method works, along with an important addition mentioned in my answer. See below.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I answered my own question. Here's what I did:

1) The answer is don't use `brew`. I installed `vim` using MacPorts instead. See https://www.macports.org/ for information and installation instructions. Also see my second link in OP. To install `vim` with MacPorts, do

```
sudo port install vim +python37
```

You can check all the variants MacPorts offers by doing

```
port variant vim
```

To uninstall `vim`, simply do

```
sudo port uninstall vim
```

2) I edited my `~/.bash_profile` file in the following way:

```
PATH="/Users/user/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/${PATH}"
export PATH
```

After these two changes, my `vim --version` in fact returned `+python3` and I no longer got an error to do with `vim` being compiled with `python` instead of `python3`.

Hope this can help someone else out in the future.